# Telling if a coord is inside a circle and forms part of a circumference

Tags: geometry, algebraic-geometry

I have, roughly speaking, this: [image]

I know `x1,y1` and `x2,y2` (the center of the yellow circle and the red circumference), and I know `r1` and `r2` (the radius of both).

Is there a way I can tell if a coord (a pair of two random numbers) is somewhere *inside* the yellow circle and belongs to the red circumference?

Said with other words, can I find if a coord belongs to the blue part of the circumference?

Comment: the *coord (pair of two random numbers)* you are checking is referred to the 1st or to the 2nd reference system?

Comment: @GCab to the first, aka, to the yellow circle. You can also assume that x1,y1 will always be 0,0. Meaning, the yellow circle is the center of everything.

Comment: ok, then Benson's answer applies

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To check if a point $P(a,b)$ is in a circle with radius $r$ centered at $(x,y)$, it must satisfy the following inequality:

$$
(a-x)^2 + (b-y)^2 \le r^2
$$

To check if a point $P(a,b)$ is on the circumference of a circle with radius $r$ centered at $(x,y)$, it must satisfy the following equality:

$$
(a-x)^2 + (b-y)^2 = r^2
$$

Thus in order for a point to be on the blue part of the circumference, that point $P(a,b)$  must satisfy $(a-x_1)^2 + (b-y_1)^2 \le r_1^2$, and $(a-x_2)^2 + (b-y_2)^2 = r_2^2$

EDIT:

To answer the extra question given about the minimum length of $r_2$ such that the blue part has more than 1 point, consider the length of $r_2$ such that there is exactly 1 point of contact. This occurs when $(x_1-x_2)^2 + (y_1-y_2)^2 = (r_1+r_2)^2$. In order for there to be more than 1 point on the blue part, we simply need to choose a value for $r_2$ such that $(x_1-x_2)^2 + (y_1-y_2)^2 < (r_1+r_2)^2$.

*Edited to fix bad formatting.*

Comment: Let me check your solution :)

Comment: Extra question: Can I know the minimum value of r2 (granted that I know x1,y1 and x2,y2 and r1) that would allow the circumference and the circle to intersect in more than 1 point?

Answer (score 1):

The distance of your random point (x, y) to the center of the yellow circle is $d=\sqrt{(x-x_1)^2+(y-y_1)^2}.$ Your point is within the yellow circle if $d < r_1$. Furthermore, your point is on the red circumference if $(x-x_2)^2 + (y-y_2)^2 = r_2^2\;.$ Just check if (x, y) fullfilles both conditions.
*Extra question*: The distance between the two midpoints is $D=\sqrt{(x_2-x_1)^2+(y_2-y_1)^2}.$ The circles intersect if $r_1+r_2>D.$